# Upgrade Error 5.35 to 5.47

Tags: upgrade

```
$ManagedEntities_failed = Array
(
    [entity] => SearchDisplay
    [action] => create
    [params] => Array
        (
            [version] => 4
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [name] => AfAdmin_Submission_List_Display
                    [label] => Form Submissions Table
                    [saved_search_id.name] => AfAdmin_Submission_List
                    [type] => table
                    [actions] => 1
                    [acl_bypass] =>
                    [settings] => Array
                        (
                            [actions] => 1
                            [limit] => 50
                            [classes] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => table
                                    [1] => table-striped
                                )
...
            [checkPermissions] =>
        )

    [result] => Array
        (
            [error_code] => not-found
            [entity] =>
            [action] =>
            [is_error] => 1
            [error_message] => API (SearchDisplay, create) does not exist (join the API team and implement it!)
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you do not have a Search kit extension installed which is required by the Form Builder extension.

Can you do the following?

1. Install Search Kit extension
2. Upgrade CiviCRM 5.47

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thank you, enabled the search kit extension before upgrading civicrm